# How to restore pretrained checkpoint for current model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a pretrained checkpoint. And now I'm trying to restore this pretrained model to the current network. However, variable names are different. [Tensorflow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#choose_variables_to_save_and_restore) says that using dictionary like:

```
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", [5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
saver = tf.train.Saver({"v2": v2})
```

However, variables in current network are defined like:

```
with tf.variable_scope('a'):
    b=tf.get_variable(......)
```

So, the variable name seems to be `a/b`. 
How to make the dictionary like `"v2": a/b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)`to get a list of all variable names in current graph. You also can specify scope.

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='a')
```

You can use `tf.train.list_variables(ckpt_file)` to get a list of all variables in checkpoint.

Suppose you have variable b in your checkpoint, and you want to load inside `tf.variable_scope('a')` under name `a/b`. To do that you just define it

```
with tf.variable_scope('a'):
    b=tf.get_variable(......)
```

And load

```
saver = tf.train.Saver({'v2': b})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file))
    print(b)
```

This will output

```
<tf.Variable 'a/b:0' shape dtype>
```

Edit: As mentioned earlier you can get variable names with

```
vars_dict = {}
for var_current in tf.global_variables():
    print(var_current)
    print(var_current.op.name) # this gets only name

for var_ckpt in tf.train.list_variables(ckpt):
    print(var_ckpt[0]) this gets only name
```

When you know exact names of all variables you can assign whatever value you need, provided variables have same shape and dtype
So to get a dict

```
vars_dict[var_ckpt[0]) = tf.get_variable(var_current.op.name, shape) # remember to specify shape, you can always get it from var_current
```

You can construct this dictionary either explicitly or in any kind of loop you'll see fit. And then you pass it to saver

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(vars_dict)
```

Comment: I got variables from checkpoint using: `tf.train.list_variables(ckpt_file)`. And variables in current graph using `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='a')`. The dictionary for saver looks like: `{'generator/bn1_audio/batch_normalization/beta': 'mfcc_encoder/bn1_audio/batch_normalization/beta'}`. But I got this error: TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string).

Comment: When you specify scope, you'll get only variables from this scope. To get all variables you don't need it. Then you'll get `'scope_name/var_name'`

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606298/how-to-restore-weights-with-different-names-but-same-shapes-tensorflow). But, my problem is, the variables to restore are not in the same file with `saver`. So, I don't know how to define the values of the dictionary.

Comment: So you have current variables, and you need to load their values from checkpoint where variables have same shape but another names, right ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. And I know the key is the variable name in the checkpoint, the value is the current variable. But the dict and variables are not in the same function. Situation is not as easy as the TF document. I'm confusing how to define the values of the dict.

Comment: If the `saver` and variables to restore are in the same function, the way shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606298/how-to-restore-weights-with-different-names-but-same-shapes-tensorflow) can be used. But, in most cases, they are not in the same function. How to solve this situation?

Comment: Updated answer. This should be unambiguous

Comment: I find way maybe could solve this problem. The thing it want is the Tensor or Variable in current graph. And I know the tensor name. So, I define the dict like this: `{'a/b/filter': sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('c/b/filter:0')}`

Comment: yes that's exactly what I updated my answer with. to get value from current graph you can just get it from `global_variables`. Hope it solves your problem